# Android: Difference between onInterceptTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent?

Tags: java, android, event-handling, event-listener, android-touch-event

What is the difference between `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `dispatchTouchEvent` in Android?

According to the android developer guide, both methods can be used to intercept a touch event (`MotionEvent`), but what is the difference?

How do `onInterceptTouchEvent`, `dispatchTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` interact together within a hierarchy of Views (`ViewGroup`)?

Answer (score 301):

The best place to demystify this is the source code. The docs are woefully inadequate about explaining this.

dispatchTouchEvent is actually defined on Activity, View and ViewGroup. **Think of it as a controller which decides how to route the touch events.**

For example, the simplest case is that of **View.dispatchTouchEvent** which will route the touch event to either **OnTouchListener.onTouch** if it's defined or to the extension method **onTouchEvent**.

For **ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent** things are way more complicated. It needs to figure out which one of its child views should get the event (by calling child.dispatchTouchEvent). This is basically a hit testing algorithm where you figure out which child view's bounding rectangle contains the touch point coordinates.

But before it can dispatch the event to the appropriate child view, the parent can spy and/or intercept the event all together. This is what **onInterceptTouchEvent** is there for. So it calls this method first before doing the hit testing and if the event was hijacked (by returning true from onInterceptTouchEvent) it sends a **ACTION_CANCEL** to the child views so they can abandon their touch event processing (from previous touch events) and from then onwards all touch events at the parent level are dispatched to **onTouchListener.onTouch** (if defined) or **onTouchEvent**(). Also in that case, onInterceptTouchEvent is never called again.

Would you even want to override [Activity|ViewGroup|View].dispatchTouchEvent? Unless you are doing some custom routing you probably should not.

The main extension methods are ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent if you want to spy and/or intercept touch event at the parent level and View.onTouchListener/View.onTouchEvent for main event handling.

All in all its overly complicated design imo but android apis lean more towards flexibility than simplicity.

Comment: This is a great, concise answer. For a more detailed example, see the training ["Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup"](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Comment: @numan salati : "from then onwards all touch events at the parent level are dispatched to onTouchListener.onTouch" - I want to override the dispatch touch method in my view group and make it dispatch the events to onTouchListener. But I don't see how it can be done. There is not api for that like View.getOnTouchListener().onTouch(). There is a setOnTouchListener() method but no getOnTouchListener() method. How can it be done then?

Comment: @Ashwin my thoughts exactly, there is not setOnInterceptTouchEvent either. You can Override a subclass view for use in a layout/adding it in code, but you cannot mess around with fragment/activity-level rootViews, since you can't subclass those views without subclassing the fragment/activity itself (like in most compatibility ProgressActivitiy implementations). API needs a setOnInterceptTouchEvent for simplicity. Everybody uses interceptTouch on rootViews at some point in a semi-complex App

Comment: I thought I understand this mechanism until I discovered that calls on dispatchTouchEvent() and onInterceptTouchEvent() depend on which ViewGroups are set clickable.

Answer (score 265):

Because this is the first result on Google. I want to share with you a great Talk by Dave Smith on [Youtube: Mastering the Android Touch System](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) and the slides are available [here](https://speakerdeck.com/newcircle/dave-smith-mastering-the-android-touch-system). It gave me a good deep understanding about the Android Touch System:

How the **Activity** handles touch:

> - `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()`
>
>   - Always  first  to  be  called
>   - Sends  event  to  root  view  attached  to  Window
>   - `onTouchEvent()`
>
>     - Called  if  no  views  consume  the  event
>     - Always  last  to  be  called

How the **View** handles touch:

> - `View.dispatchTouchEvent()`
>
>   - Sends  event  to  listener  first,  if  exists
>
>     - `View.OnTouchListener.onTouch()`
>   - If  not  consumed,  processes  the  touch  itself
>
>     - `View.onTouchEvent()`

How a **ViewGroup** handles touch:

> - `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()`
>
>   - `onInterceptTouchEvent()`
>
>     - Check  if  it  should  supersede  children
>     - Passes  `ACTION_CANCEL`  to  active  child
>     - If it returns  true  once,  the `ViewGroup` consumes  all  subsequent  events
>   - For  each  child  view  (in  reverse  order  they  were  added)
>
>     - If  touch  is  relevant  (inside  view),  `child.dispatchTouchEvent()`
>     - If  it is not  handled  by  a previous,  dispatch  to  next  view
>   - If  no  children  handles the  event, the listener  gets  a  chance
>
>     - `OnTouchListener.onTouch()`
>   - If there is no listener, or its not handled
>
>     - `onTouchEvent()`
> - Intercepted  events  jump  over the child step

He also provides example code of custom touch on [github.com/devunwired/](https://github.com/devunwired/custom-touch-examples).

**Answer:**
Basically the `dispatchTouchEvent()` is called on every `View` layer to determine if a `View` is interested in an ongoing gesture. In a `ViewGroup` the `ViewGroup` has the ability to steal the touch events in his `dispatchTouchEvent()`-method, before it would call `dispatchTouchEvent()` on the children. The `ViewGroup` would only stop the dispatching if the `ViewGroup` `onInterceptTouchEvent()`-method returns true. The **difference** is that `dispatchTouchEvent()`is dispatching `MotionEvents` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` tells if it should intercept *(not dispatching the `MotionEvent` to children)* or not *(dispatching to children)*.

You could imagine the [code of a ViewGroup](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java/#1834) doing more-or-less this (very simplified):

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(!onInterceptTouchEvent()){
        for(View child : children){
            if(child.dispatchTouchEvent(ev))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 99):

## Supplemental Answer

Here are some visual supplements to the other answers. My full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862320/3681880).

[image]

[image]

The `dispatchTouchEvent()` method of a `ViewGroup` uses `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to choose whether it should immediately handle the touch event (with `onTouchEvent()`) or continue notifying the `dispatchTouchEvent()` methods of its children.

Comment: Can onInterceptTouchEvent  be called also in the activity?? I think it is possible only in a ViewGroup or I'm wrong? @Suragch

Comment: @FedericoRizzo, You're right! Thank you very much! I updated the diagram and my answer.

Answer (score 23):

There is a lot of confusion about these methods, but it is actually not that complicated. Most of the confusion is because:

1. If your `View/ViewGroup` or any of its children do not return true in
   `onTouchEvent`, `dispatchTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` will ONLY
   be called for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. Without a true from
   `onTouchEvent`, the parent view will assume your view does not need
   the MotionEvents.
2. When none of the children of a ViewGroup return true in onTouchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent will ONLY be called for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, even if your ViewGroup returns true in `onTouchEvent`.

Processing order is like this:

1. `dispatchTouchEvent` is called.
2. `onInterceptTouchEvent` is called for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` or when
   any of the children of the ViewGroup returned true in `onTouchEvent`.
3. `onTouchEvent` is first called on the children of the ViewGroup and
   when none of the children returns true it is called on the
   `View/ViewGroup`.

If you want to preview `TouchEvents/MotionEvents` without disabling the events on your children, you must do two things:

1. Override `dispatchTouchEvent` to preview the event and return
   `super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)`;
2. Override `onTouchEvent` and return true, otherwise you won’t get any
   `MotionEvent`  except `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

If you want to detect some gesture like a swipe event, without disabling other events on your children as long as you did not detect the gesture, you can do it like this:

1. Preview the MotionEvents as described above and set a flag when you
   detected your gesture.
2. Return true in `onInterceptTouchEvent` when your flag is set to cancel
   MotionEvent  processing by your children. This is also a convenient
   place to reset your flag, because onInterceptTouchEvent won’t be
   called again until the next `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Example of overrides in a `FrameLayout` (my example in is C# as I’m programming with Xamarin Android, but the logic is the same in Java):

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    // Preview the touch event to detect a swipe:
    switch (e.ActionMasked)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            _processingSwipe = false;
            _touchStartPosition = e.RawX;
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            if (!_processingSwipe)
            {
                float move = e.RawX - _touchStartPosition;
                if (move >= _swipeSize)
                {
                    _processingSwipe = true;
                    _cancelChildren = true;
                    ProcessSwipe();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
}

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    // To make sure to receive touch events, tell parent we are handling them:
    return true;
}

public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    // Cancel all children when processing a swipe:
    if (_cancelChildren)
    {
        // Reset cancel flag here, as OnInterceptTouchEvent won't be called until the next MotionEventActions.Down:
        _cancelChildren = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes. It's a good answer (IMO) and I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:** `dispatchTouchEvent()` will be called **first** of all.

**Short advice:** should not override `dispatchTouchEvent()` since it's hard to control, sometimes it can slow down your performance. IMHO, I suggest overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

---

Because most answers mention pretty clearly about the flow touch event on activity/ view group/ view, I only add more detail about code on these methods in `ViewGroup` (ignoring `dispatchTouchEvent()`):

**`onInterceptTouchEvent()`** will be called first, ACTION event will be called respectively down -> move -> up. There are 2 cases:

1. If you **return false** in 3 cases (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP), it will consider as the **parent won't need this touch event**, so **`onTouch()` of the parents never calls**, but **`onTouch()` of the children will call instead**; however please notice:

   - The `onInterceptTouchEvent()` still continue to receive touch event, as long as its children don't call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`.
   - If there are no children receiving that event (it can happen in 2 cases: no children at the position the users touch, or there are children but it returns false at ACTION_DOWN), the parents will send that event back to `onTouch()` of the parents.
2. Vice versa, if you **return true**, the **parent will steal this touch event** immediately, and `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will stop immediately, instead **`onTouch()` of the parents will be called** as well as all **`onTouch()` of children will receive** the last action event - **ACTION_CANCEL** (thus, it means the parents stole touch event, and children cannot handle it from then on). The flow of `onInterceptTouchEvent()` return false is normal, but there is a little confusion with return true case, so I list it here:

   - Return true at ACTION_DOWN, `onTouch()` of the parents will receive ACTION_DOWN **again** and following actions (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP).
   - Return true at ACTION_MOVE, `onTouch()` of the parents will receive **next** ACTION_MOVE (not the same ACTION_MOVE in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`) and following actions (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP).
   - Return true at ACTION_UP, `onTouch()` of the parents will **NOT** called at all since it's too late for the parents to steal touch event.

One more thing **important** is ACTION_DOWN of the event in `onTouch()` will determine if the view would like to receive more action from that event or not. If the view returns true at ACTION_DOWN in `onTouch()`, it means the view is willing to receive more action from that event. Otherwise, return false at ACTION_DOWN in `onTouch()` will imply that the view won't receive any more action from that event.

Answer (score 9):

I came accross very intuitive explanation at this webpage http://doandroids.com/blogs/tag/codeexample/. Taken from there:

> - boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) - called whenever a touch event with this View as target is detected
> - boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) - called whenever a touch event is detected with this ViewGroup or a child of it as target. If this function returns true, the MotionEvent will be intercepted, meaning it will be not be passed on to the child, but rather to the onTouchEvent of this View.

Comment: question is about onInterceptTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent. Both are call before onTouchEvent. But in that example you cant see dispatchTouchEvent.

Answer (score 9):

dispatchTouchEvent handles before onInterceptTouchEvent.

Using this simple example:

```
   main = new LinearLayout(this){
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            System.out.println("Event - onInterceptTouchEvent");
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            //return false; //event get propagated
        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            System.out.println("Event - dispatchTouchEvent");
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            //return false; //event DONT get propagated
        }
    };

    main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    main.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,480));    


    viewA = new EditText(this);
    viewA.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    viewA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    viewA.setTextSize(16);
    viewA.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,80));
    main.addView(viewA);

    setContentView(main);
```

You can see that the log willl be like:

```
I/System.out(25900): Event - dispatchTouchEvent
I/System.out(25900): Event - onInterceptTouchEvent
```

So in case you are working with these 2 handlers use dispatchTouchEvent to handle on first instance the event, which will go to onInterceptTouchEvent.

Another difference is that if dispatchTouchEvent return 'false' the event dont get propagated to the child, in this case the EditText, whereas if you return false in onInterceptTouchEvent the event still get dispatch to the EditText

Answer (score 4):

The following code within a ViewGroup subclass would prevent it's parent containers from receiving touch events:

```
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Normal event dispatch to this container's children, ignore the return value
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    // Always consume the event so it is not dispatched further up the chain
    return true;
  }
```

I used this with a custom overlay to prevent background views from responding to touch events.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYoN-OvdZ3M&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=19 and the next 3 videos. All the touch events are explained very well, it's very clear and full of examples.

Comment: These are really good videos, I watched a few and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference :

> •Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) - This allows your Activity
>   to intercept all touch events before they are dispatched to the
>   window. 
>   •ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) - This allows a
>   ViewGroup to watch events as they are dispatched to child Views.

Comment: Yes, I know this answers from android dev guide - nevertheless unclear. The method dispatchTouchEvent exists also for a ViewGroup not only for an Activity. My question was, how the three methods dispatchTouchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent interact together within a hierarchy of ViewGroups e.g. RelativeLayouts.

Answer (score 2):

ViewGroup's `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is always the entry point for `ACTION_DOWN` event which is first event to occur.

If you want ViewGroup to process this gesture, return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.
On returning true, ViewGroup's `onTouchEvent()` will receive all subsequent events till next `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL`, and in most cases, the touch events between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` are `ACTION_MOVE`, which will normally be recognized as scrolling/fling gestures.

If you return false from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, the target view's `onTouchEvent()` will be called. It will be repeated for subsequent messages till you return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Source:
http://neevek.net/posts/2013/10/13/implementing-onInterceptTouchEvent-and-onTouchEvent-for-ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean consume =false;
    if(onInterceptTouchEvent(ev){
        consume = onTouchEvent(ev);
    }else{
        consume = child.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Both Activity and View have method dispatchTouchEvent() and onTouchEvent.The ViewGroup have this methods too, but have another method called onInterceptTouchEvent. The return type of those methods are boolean, you can control the dispatch route through the return value.

The event dispatch in Android starts from Activity->ViewGroup->View.

Answer (score -1):

Small answer:

onInterceptTouchEvent comes before setOnTouchListener.