# Consuming touch event prevents me from detecting future events

Tags: android, google-maps, events, listener, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem with my app : I have a FrameLayout with a Fragment which contains a map from the Google Maps Android APi (v2), and a customized view which I use to display various buttons on top of the map.

I'd like some of these elements not to be shown while the map is being moved, for this I use the onTouchEvent() function of the View :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        pressed = true;
        invalidate();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        pressed = false;
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The onDraw() function only displays the elements drawn over the map if `pressed == false;`

Now, my problem is in the return : if I put false, I say the event wasn't consumed, and the Android OS no longer notifies me when touch events are recorded, thus the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP isn't detected and the buttons stay hidden. If I put true, the touch events are no longer detected this time by the GoogleMap object, and I can't move the map around. Is there a way to keep detecting all future touch events, while not consuming the first event ?

Comment: Have you found a workaround eventually? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onInterceptTouchEvent` or `dispatchTouchEvent`.

You may read about the differences here: [Android: Difference between onInterceptTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have no idea how I am supposed to use this. Could you explain what you have in mind ?