# RecylerView does not scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I'm using `RecylerView` in my Android app, for each row, I used 1 line for Text and 1 line for containing 3 buttons. The problem is: if I hold the position in the region of buttons and drag UP/DOWN, 
`RecylerView` does not scroll. But if I hold and drag other positions (Not in region of buttons), It scrolls normally.

```
public static boolean inRegion(float x, float y, View v) {
        int[] location = new int[8];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        return location[0] + v.getWidth() > x && location[1] + v.getHeight() > y 
                && location[0] < x && location[1] < y;
    }

 public static View getMapView(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View mapView = null;
        int size = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i) ;
            if (view.getTag() != null && view.getTag() instanceof String) {
                String tag = (String) view.getTag();
                if (tag.equals("MapView"))
                    return view;
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                mapView = getMapView((ViewGroup) view);
                if (mapView != null)
                    break;
            }

        }
        return mapView;
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        View view = getMapView(this);
        boolean r = false;
        if (view != null) {
            r = inRegion(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(), view);
        }
        if (r == false)
            return super.onInterceptHoverEvent(event);
        else
            return false;
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you modified the behavior of the buttons' touch listeners. Remove that and your RecyclerView should work fine.

Comment: Could you please give me more details? Because I just us onClick listener for these button

Comment: I'm so sorry, source code relates to our team's project, Not my personal project :|

Comment: you don't have to show anything specific to the business, just the part that doesn't work. you can mask off anything that would potentially show what the app is about.

Comment: After debugging, I found that this issue happens because I used onInterceptTouchEvent(). I added source code in my question, please check!

Comment: why do you need to override this?

Comment: I do this to make sure it will not perform any action if users click on each row and require users to click 1 of 3 buttons instead

Comment: you're returning `super.onInterceptHoverEvent(event)`, try just the regular old `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Also, try returning the super call instead of false.

Comment: there's a very good read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22490810/611228) that talks about modifying android touch event