# How can i position my views like this? onLayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewgroup

[sign off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKkWd.jpg)

Im trying to position my views (just the dots pattern) like in this photo with no success.
can someone please help me figure out how i should do it using onLayout?
Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    int curWidth, curHeight, curLeft, curTop, maxHeight;

    //get the available size of child view
    int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
    int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();
    int childRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.circle_width) - this.getPaddingRight();
    int childBottom = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.circle_width) - this.getPaddingBottom();
    int childWidth = childRight - childLeft;
    int childHeight = childBottom - childTop;

    maxHeight = 0;
    curLeft = childLeft;
    curTop = childTop;
    //walk through each child, and arrange it from left to right
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            //Get the maximum size of the child
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
            curWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            curHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            //wrap is reach to the end
            if (curLeft + curWidth >= childRight) {
                curLeft = childLeft;
                curTop += maxHeight;
                maxHeight = 0;
            }

            //do the layout
            child.layout(curLeft, curTop, curLeft + curWidth, curTop + curHeight);

            //store the max height
            if (maxHeight < curHeight)
                maxHeight = curHeight;
            curLeft += curWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you shouldn't do that inside `onLayout`, its called multiple times and you probably don't need this. why not preparing inside `constructor` or if dots just draw inside `onDraw`, will be more efficient than adding lot of `View`s with only simple bitmap. maybe show some screen what you have, is there should be any animation?

Comment: the layout supposed to be a pattern lock. i just need to draw this 3 dots and connect between them when i want to approve my action like in this photo. the photo is actually the wanted result after i do the pattern.

Comment: do you want a static image without interaction with `MotionEvent`s or whole drawing lines through other dots animation/interaction?

Comment: its supposed do function like a LockPattern. when i press on image the color should be white (i change the drawable) and draw a line in a V pattern to approve my action. i want the user to be able to draw the line only between the dots.

Comment: so you have to override [onInterceptTouchEvent  and/or dispatchTouchEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent) and using overriden `onDraw` method [draw your lines on `Canvas`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android) according to `MotionEvent`s position. It's bigger case, solid piece of code needed to work. For sure `onLayout` isn't best place to put drawing code

Answer (score 0):

Its easy actually you can build it in XML layout. In it's simplest representation it just three dot view that are vertically displaced from each other.  Define a Linear Layout with vertical orientation with weight sum = 3 , layout three view with weight = 1. Then use layout margin to shift each view relative to each other. A perfect layout for such a scenario would be Contraint Layout which is more flexible.

Here is a great tutorial to incorporate custom gesture handling,http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-add-customized-gesture-controls-to-your-android-1705180921

Comment: also do not perform graphical such as that in onLayout, try constructors.

Comment: can i implement Pattern Lock on a XML layout? i need to approve action with this pattern.

Comment: what you mean exactly layout wise, if yes then certainly.

Comment: you could add super powers to it, by enabling gestures on screen

Comment: simple swipe gestures like a pattern

Comment: okay, i built a layout like i needed to. now im trying to figure out  how to implement the gesture detecture and draw the line between the views and how to set the correct pattern. any ideas?