# Detect gesture over everthing

Tags: android, touch, gesture

How can I detect any gesture in my Activity, even with many things there (`Layouts`, `Images`, `RecyclerViews`, etc).
I intent to create an gesture that can be done at any time.
Is it possible?

I've tried this:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("GESTURE", "GESTURE");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But it's not working. I think it's because the others views is intercepting the event.

Idk if is it possible to detect the gesture above the activity, like in the window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's a bit tricky. Read up on touch handling and especially `onInterceptTouchEvent`, which can be used on a parent to intercept touches going to the children.

You would implement that method in a (custom) root view, and then do your gesture magic in there.

Some valuable info here: [Android: Difference between onInterceptTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent)

Comment: It worked. I just override the method "dispatchTouchEvent" in my activity. Thank you!