# How to temporarily disable all touch on screen and enable it again

Tags: android

How to disable all touch event when a process is running on `Fragments`. Our device has a built-in printer in it. while printing and rapidly tapping the screen it makes the app crash, How can I assure that the screen is untouchable?. I have tried to use

`getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`

and

`getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`

and the crash still occurs. I also try to add an ID on my parent `LinearLayout` and try to enable and disable it. but still, nothing happens?. What is the alternative code for it? Thanks!

Error Logs

`02-26 18:16:37.000 18941-18946/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-26 18:16:37.060 18941-18946/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-26 18:16:37.110 18941-18941/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos I/HAL_JNI: - native_printer_close(), result = 0
02-26 18:16:37.130 18941-18941/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos I/Choreographer: Skipped 357 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.02-26 18:16:40.740 18941-18941/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000419 (code=0), thread 18941 (i.mikee.jti_pos)`

XML Layout

https://ghostbin.com/paste/ob2fa

Comment: you can take one transparent `view` over your fragment. and while your background process is going on make, `setClickable` to true for that view and after completing make it false again.

Comment: i would like to suggest you to learn a little deep about touch events **onInterceptTouchEvent** vs **dispatchTouchEvent** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent)

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace with your crash? IF yes, can you post it? I ask because disabling all touch events sounds like an extreme solution to any problem.

Comment: @PPartisan post updated

Comment: Ok, so it's an ANR rather than a crash - can you extract that traces file? run `adb shell cat /data/anr/traces.txt` or `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt {local_path_to_save_file}` and read the contents. Evidently something is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I have tried to run it but it says device not found. sorry new on this retrieving traces.txt

Comment: When you're connected to a device that's experienced this issue via adb, run `adb shell` then `cd /data/anr/` and see what's inside with `ls`. Get the filename (if there is one), `exit`, and then pull to your current directory with `adb pull /data/anr/{file_name}`. There is some more info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr)

I don't think trying to prevent touch events will solve your problem - you need to ensure long running tasks are executed off the UI thread.

Comment: permission denied on `cd data`. I guess that's our device manufactuer security.

Comment: @MikeGorospe Yes, you wont be able to on a `user` build, it needs to be a `userdebug` build, with debugging enabled. You could try running `adb root; adb remount` but that probably wont be enough.

Best bet then is to try and profile your app and find out what's blocking the UI thread. The links I posted above can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by using a trick.

- Show a transparent view above your root view to disable click.
- Hide that view for enable clicks

Thank you

Comment: Is it `LinearLayout`? or other components?

Comment: Anything with transparent background. You can take LinearLayout also.

Comment: I have tried this 


 `<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/supervisoryOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout> ` but the layout is now blank

Comment: Please check the ghostbin file

Comment: visible when you want to disable click gone when you want to enable click

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I will call this once the button print is pressed and hide it when done printing?

Comment: I have tried the `FrameLayout` but after pressing. It makes the device print first rather than showing the `FrameLayout` first

Answer (score 0):

override dispatchTouchEvent in activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!isSomethingInProcess) {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use `Fragment` and the printing is on `Fragment` only

Comment: define a variable in your activity like "boolean isSomethingInProcess".. when your process starts in fragment, try to set variable like this ((YourActivity)getActivity).isSomethingInProcess = true;  it will handle the rest.. don't forget to put above method (dispatchTouchEvent) to your activity