# GestureDetector not working for Android PdfViewer lib

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, pdf-viewer

**GestureDetector** working fine when i tap on empty activity screen but it's not working when I tap on Android pdfViewer(means pdf document)....Please help me how to do it.

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            //------------------apply your logic here------------
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    });      

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Document opened in Android PdfViewer

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

when i click outside of opened doc GestureDetector working fine but when i click on pdf document GestureDetector not wrok.

Comment: Can you share some code with us to see what you are trying to do?

Comment: @tomerpacific Question edited with code.

Answer (score 1):

Got Answer from [Abhay Koradiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7783718/abhay-koradiya),

issue was onTouchEvent that not called if pdfviewer attached => This hapen because pdfviewer already consumed touch event.

So you need to use

> dispatchTouchEvent

instead of that. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent/22490810#22490810)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```