# Is there a way to detect touch in pdf using flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

I'm using [dart pdf library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) and I want to detect touch on screen while the pdf is being viewed. Is there a way to do that? For viewing the pdf file I'm using a `PDFViewerScaffold` with the created file's path. I tried wrapping the `PDFViewerScaffold` with `Listener` and `GestureDetector`, but no luck.
My code so far:

*Viewing the pdf file:*

```
class PdfViewerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String path;
  const PdfViewerPage({Key key, this.path}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFViewerScaffold(
          path: path,
    );
  }
}
```

*Making the pdf file*:

```
final Document pdf = Document();

...

pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
      pageFormat:
      ...
      footer: (Context context) {
        ...
      },
      build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
        ...
...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I checked this library but i did not find any GestureDetector widget, it seems this library dose not support GestureDetector yet.

Comment: The _dart pdf library_ only creates a pdf file. It can neither show the file nor interact with user. That's why it doesn't have a GestureDetector. I'm using _flutter full pdf viewer_ library to show the pdf file. @Taleb

Comment: Oh, i test it with printing library,
i will try flutter_full_pdf_viewer  now..

Comment: if you just want the gesture you should wrap it with your main Scaffold and GestureDetector :
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          print('tap');
        },
          child: PDFViewerScaffold(path: 'assets/pdf/flutter_tutorial.pdf')),
    );

Comment: I've already tried this, it doesn't work. @Taleb

Comment: What do you want to do with touch on pdf ??? (please explain more about what you want to do exactly )

Comment: I want the user to choose the contents of the pdf file, so I need to detect tap on different spots of the screen while the user is viewing the pdf file (like when a tap is detected on the right side of the screen, it generates the pdf file again but with new contents). @Taleb

Comment: please follow this tutorial => 
https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/getting-started-with-pspdfkit-flutter/

and also clone this repository and checkout test example your self => 
https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-flutter

Comment: Unfortunately PSPDFKit is not free to use, thank you though. @Taleb

Comment: I try it with no licence key at this moment and it works for me .

Comment: have you tried going native and getting data through methodchannel  as there are solution in android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861608/gesturedetector-not-working-for-android-pdfviewer-lib

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back, FlutterFullPdfViewer uses native component and encapsulate it in a FrameLayout(in android) that can only be manipulated through native code.
What I did is that I forked the project, and added my own implementation.
In the android part you have a method called in FlutterFullPdfViewerManager.java :

```
void openPDF(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    pdfView.fromFile(file)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .defaultPage(0)
            .load();
}
```

You can change this to:

```
void openPDF(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    pdfView.fromFile(file)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .onTap(e-> {
                if (e.getRawX() > 300) {//put your value here
                    //send rebuild instruction to flutter
                }
            .defaultPage(0)
            .load();
}
```

Or something along these lines, you will also find that there is a lot of extra stuff that you can do on pdfView that could be helpful to you.